# How to only mark file not folder using glob pattern?

Tags: gulp, gitignore, glob

Consider the following file structure:

```
root
   |- folder1
   |- folder2
   |- folderN
   |- file1
   |- file2
   |- fileN
```

How to target only files without excluding (`!`) each folder one by one?

Comment: if there is finite list of extensions specify it using extensions `**\*.[js|css|html]`

Comment: Can you clarify? Which one of those files and folders do you want to have selected?

Comment: @ddprrt files 1 to n should be selected.

Answer (score 2):

So you just want the files in that certain root directory, without the folders **and** contents of those folders.

The glob you are looking for is `*`. This one selects all the files inside the directory you are currently. Or use `root/*` if you want to select all the files inside the `root` folder **without** its subfolders. To select subfolders and subfolder content, you have to use the Globstar: `**`

You can test your glob easily [here](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzTAgAAKwAr&r=eJyzScksU0jOSSwutlVSskvLz0lJLTLUT8vMSbXRB0rZ2aDI2xQXJOYpFJdU5qTaKqXl55XoFmdWpVopGFrqGRVUWMMMMIIaAFJtZ5NUZEeBWcYoZhHSA7EMohbDztzEkuQMYiwGWmhIFVOMqGKKMYopAONukWs%3D&):

Comment: Thanks. While your linked site show the desired result, it actually will mach folders without content. If for example you want use that glob to copy that place to anther location using gulp, if will copy empty folders as well.